# HTML5 Canvas, registering click events for each rectangle

Tags: jquery, html, canvas, ember.js

[image]

This is a color bar which a draw on a HTML5 Canvas. Each color bar represnets a time stamp like 00:30 or 05:45 etc.

These color bars are basically the rectangles that i draw over the canvas.

I want to register a click event for each of the rectangle so that i can show the timestamp and update other stuff on the page. Can anybody help here, how to register click event for each of the rectangle? Do i need to use some other elements like section or more canvases?

BTW, i am using EmberJS, so updating data isn't an issue.

**UPDATE**

Here is a JSfiddle from a different stackoverflow question.
  `http://jsfiddle.net/DV9Bw/`

```
draw: function(index, score){
    var canvas = this.get('element')
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.fillStyle=this.get('colorCodes')[Math.round(score)];
    ctx.fillRect(index*3,0,3,150);
    this.drawLastAmbiant()
```

Just see that, it returning us the value of color but i want to show some other data as well.

Comment: It is not possible to recommend anything without any markup?

Comment: No individual items are clickable in a CANVAS, only the entire element. But you could still use kind of workaround using absolute positioned elements on top of canvas

Comment: you could use a framework like http://createjs.com/#!/EaselJS that takes the hard workaround (like @roasted mentioned) work for you

Comment: @roasted: Yes, that can be a solution but least one. Here is a JSfiddle from another stackoverflow question which is very close to what i want, but no can't exactly fulfil my requirments. http://jsfiddle.net/DV9Bw/1/

Comment: You can not use other elements?
The example above can be done with <ul> <li>

Comment: @Falci: No, i can't use <li> here. Reason is, this bar is real time, it increases by a narrow/thin line with every minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is maybe not a *full solution* to your use case, but after messing around a bit with the example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DV9Bw/) you provided here the [results](http://jsbin.com/imasuq/14/edit).

> BTW, i am using EmberJS, so updating data isn't an issue.

I've first ***emberyfied*** the example to reflect the use of ember.

The tricky part I guess is on how do you **map/relate** the data contained in your ember `model` record with the clicked bar in your canvas, because the clicked element does not have a relation to your model neither the data.

A possible workaround could be to calculate the bar's index with the current mouse coordinates  when a bar is clicked, and lookup the related data by the calculated index with `objectAt(index)`.

Please have a look at the provided [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/imasuq/14/edit) for a possible workaround **(without the use of any framework for simplicity)**, it might be a somewhat naive approach which can be further improved, but as a starting point it seams to work so far.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Nice effort man. Really what i was a looking for. I have start using EaselJs as per ur suggestion in a comment. Easel is also good but not as much accurate as your ur jsbin

Comment: before switching back from EasalJS, will your solution work in case of responsiveness? My color bar's width is in percentage and can shrink and expand upon windows size. it seems to be fix 400 in jsbin.

Comment: I'm afraid i hacked without reponsivness in mind :/ but it could be done of course with some recalculations when viewport size changes etc.

Comment: ahh, thanks for comment. I will try it out in a different branch. Can you update ur jsbin when you are free. I am a bit dull in making mouse and screen related pixel calculations

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it. Assuming the bar is drawn in the top left of the canvas (otherwise you need to add checks for the bounds of the area you have the bars):

```
var barWidth  = 3;   //adjust to actual width of bars
var barHeight = 150; //adjust to actual height of bars

// handlemouse-click event 
canvas.onclick= function(e) {

    var pos = getMousePos(canvas, e);
    var x = pos.x;
    var y = pos.y;

    if (y>= 0 && y <= barHeight) {    //extend the check here (offsets/width)
        var index = (x / barWidth)|0; //divide on width and round off
        alert('You clicked bar index: ' + index);
    }
}

// get mouse position relative to canvas
function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
        x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
        y: evt.clientY - rect.top
    };
}
```

Comment: really a helping answer but intuitivepixel's answer is more close to my case :). Thanks for your help.

Comment: @NadeemYasin Feel free to up-vote answers you find helpful. If intuitivepixel's answer is having the solution you're looking for you should mark his answer as accepted. :)

Answer (score 0):

Get the click event on the canvas and use the canvas's size (.offsetWidth) / number of color bars to determine the width of a bar for the current size. Then compute which bar was clicked by event.clientX / width of a bar.